# How can I send fcmtoken to the api body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

When useEffect is executed in my code, I want to get fcmtoken through firebase .getToken and send fcmtoken to body of auth/me router.

but if i use my code this error occure

```
      Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
      ReferenceError: fcmtoken is not defined
```

Perhaps the cause of the error is incorrect use of async await or anything

but how can i fix my code?

this is my code

```
    useEffect(() => {
      Linking.addEventListener('url', async ({url}) => {
        var newURL = url;
        var splitURL = newURL.toString().split('=');

        const token = splitURL[1];

        messaging()
          .getToken()
          .then((fcmtoken) => {
            return fcmtoken;
          });
        const {data} = await axios.post(
          '/auth/me',
          {fcmtoken},
          {
            headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
          },
        );
        console.log('data::::', data);

        AsyncStorage.setItem('tokenstore', `${token}`, () => {
          console.log('유저 닉네임 저장 완료');
        });

        dispatch({
          type: KAKAOLOG_IN_REQUEST,
          data: data,
        });
      });
      return () => Linking.removeEventListener('url');
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to send an undefined variable 'fcmtoken' to the API. In the code bellow I changed the way you get the fcm token.

```
    useEffect(() => {
  Linking.addEventListene`enter code here`r('url', async ({url}) => {
    var newURL = url;
    var splitURL = newURL.toString().split('=');

    const token = splitURL[1];

    let fcmtoken = await messaging().getToken();
    const {data} = await axios.post(
      '/auth/me',
      {fcmtoken},
      {
        headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
      },
    );
    console.log('data::::', data);

    AsyncStorage.setItem('tokenstore', `${token}`, () => {
      console.log('유저 닉네임 저장 완료');
    });

    dispatch({
      type: KAKAOLOG_IN_REQUEST,
      data: data,
    });
  });
  return () => Linking.removeEventListener('url');
}, []);
```